# Comparing 2 objects' values and push the values to one object array

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json, backend

I am trying to compare 2 objects by their property and the values. If the value of the "name" property matches up with each other, I want to push the property and value to value3.

Once value3 is logged, I want the response like this:

```
{
name: 'dog',
surname: 'good',
skills: 'programming',
age: '22'
},
{
name: 'cat',
surname: 'soft',
skills: 'engineer'
age: '12'
},
{
name: 'elephant',
surname: 'big',
skills: 'programming'
age: '23'
}
```

Here is the code:

```
var values1 = [
    {
    name: 'dog',
    surname: 'good',
    skills: 'programming'
    },
    {
    name: 'cat',
    surname: 'soft',
    skills: 'engineer'
    },
    {
    name: 'elephant',
    surname: 'big',
    skills: 'programming'
    }
]

var values2 = [
    {
    name: 'cat',
    food: 'fish',
    age: '12'
    },
    {
    name: 'elephant',
    food: 'leafs',
    age: '13'
    },
    {
    name: 'dog',
    food: 'treats',
    age: '22'
    }
]

// push into this empty object array
var values3 = [{}]

console.log(values3)
```

Comment: What have you done so far to achieve your goal? Is there a specific issue you're having with your solution?

Comment: yeah it is related to a different project but once I understand how to solve this, I can implement it into my project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const values1 = [
  { name: 'dog', surname: 'good', skills: 'programming' },
  { name: 'cat', surname: 'soft', skills: 'engineer' },
  { name: 'elephant', surname: 'big', skills: 'programming' }
]

const values2 = [
  { name: 'cat', food: 'fish', age: '12' },
  { name: 'elephant', food: 'leafs', age: '13' },
  { name: 'dog', food: 'treats', age: '22' }
]

const values3 = values1.map((value1) => {
  return Object.assign(value1, { age: values2.filter(value2 => value2.name === value1.name)[0].age })
})

console.log(values3)
```

The code above will only work if for each *name* in *values1* an object with *name* exists in *values2*. If not use this code:

```
const values3 = values1.map((value1) => {
  const found = values2.find(value2 => value2.name === value1.name)
  return Object.assign(value1, { age: found ? found.age : undefined })
})
```

Comment: Hey was wondering if I wanted to compare another property, could I do it like 
(value2 => value2.name === value1.name || value2.name === value1.surname)[0].age)

Comment: Yes, that will work too.